# Persist multiple directories inside docker container into single volume

Tags: docker, containers

We have  our services running inside container and with current implementation we are storing
data into multiple directories inside container like (/root/data1 , /var/some_Dir/ , /opt/some_dir).

in order to persist all this data i am passing multiple " -v  "  for each directory. 
 But i want to do this using single "-v"  (volume ) option.

Though I can put all my data  in single location  and persist  that  directory with single "-v" option.

is  there any other option for persisting multiple  directories in single volume ??????

what i am using right now is ::

docker run  -v /hostdir/1:/root/dir1  -v /hostdir/2:/var/lib/dir1. -v /hostdir/3:/opt/dir3 ........     -v /hostdir/10:/opt/dir4/logs.

i want to shorten it single "-v" option. no need to give "-v" 10 times.

Comment: Just create a mount points for your top dirs. So for instance you could have a `-v /hostdir:hostdir` and that would cover all of your internal `/hostdir/2`, `/hostdir/3`, etc mount points.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible because -v accepts host_dir/:/container_dir and its one to one mapping.

What i did was create a directory in host and then multiple folders inside that directory like ( logs,conf,temp,files ).

In that case , i configured my application to write / get files from specific folders from single directory that is been mounted.

Else you have to use -v for all directories.

Comment: How about creating symlinks? That is, a single directory (ex. /mydata) inside the container will hold all the data. And all those multiple directories will point to the /mydata directory via symliink. Then you create volume only for /mydata directory. Like `-v /host/dir:/mydata`